# Does the Log4net SMTPAppender send email Asynchronously?

Tags: asp.net, log4net

Does the Log4net `SMTPAppender` send email asynchronously? If it doesn't, how can I send logging emails asynchronously?

My log4net.config is:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="SMTPAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SMTPAppender">
      <authentication value="Basic" />
      <to value="xxx@xx.com" />
      <from value="yyy@xx.com" />
      <username value="yyy@xx.com" />
      <password value="yyy" />
      <subject value="xxx" />
      <smtpHost value="smtp.xx.com" />
      <lossy value="true" />
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="WARN" />
      </evaluator>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %newline %message%newline%newline%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO"></level>
    </root>
    <logger name="MyLogger">
      <level value="INFO"></level>
      <appender-ref ref="SMTPAppender"></appender-ref>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752456/asynchronous-logging-to-a-database-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just call the logging method asynchronously like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => log.Info("Message I want to email"));
```

I actually got this suggestion from the following SO article:

[How do I create an asynchronous wrapper for log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044497/how-do-i-create-an-asyncronous-wrapper-for-log4net)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple workaround before the solid solution is released.

```
public class SmtpAsyncAppender : SmtpAppender
{
    protected override void SendEmail(string messageBody)
    {
        Task.Run(() => base.SendEmail(messageBody));
    }
}
```

It presumes that SmtpAppender.SendEmail is thread-safe and reenterable. It is for log4net v1.2.13.0 and there is no reason not to be in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Log4net has not built in appender that is asynchronous. If you need that functionality you need to write your own appender. Downloading the log4net source code should get you started...