# Logging large volumes of actions in a production MVC/SQL application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, model-view-controller, bigdata

We are happy users of the ASP.NET MVC framework and SQL Server, currently using LINQ-to-SQL.  It serves our needs well with a consumer-facing application with about 1.4 million users and 2+ million active uniques per month.

We are long overdue to start logging **all** user actions (views of articles, searches on our site, etc.) and we're trying to scope out the right architecture to do so.

We'd like the archiving system to be its own entity, and not part of the main SQL cluster that stores the production articles and search engine.  We'd like it to be its own SQL cluster, starting out with just one box initially.

To simplify the problem, let's say we just want to log the search terms that these millions of users enter into our site for the month, and we want to do so in the least cycle-intensive-way possible.

My questions:
(1)  Is there an asynchronous way to dump the search terms to a remote box?   Does LINQ support async for this?

(2)  Would you recommend building up a cache of say 1,000 (userId, searchTerm, date) logging items in a RAM cache, and then flushing those at intervals to the database?  I assume this method would cut down on open/close connections.

Or am I thinking about this entirely wrong?  We'd like to strike a balance between ease of implementation and robustness.

Comment: This thread might have couple of good solutions for you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752456/asynchronous-logging-to-a-database-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Sure you can, there are different solution to achieve it. Linq is not the instrument you need.
2)There should not be any major improvement by doing it, the "logging" will be triggered only when a search is performed. You will end up with two calls instead of one, not a big deal.

A suggestion is to use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

You can create a clean and separate layer for logging using [Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) (there are other alternatives though). You will then decorate your actions with the required logging attribute only when you need to trace what is passed to the action. 
Main advantages with this approch are :

- Logging logic doesn't reside inside your code (you don't need to change your methods code) but is executed before/after your method.
- Clean separation of the Aspect from the target method.
- You can easily switch on/off the aspects

AOP is a common practice specially when it comes to behavior that can be added to more than one method, like logging, authentication and so on. And yes it can be used in an async way.

Answer (score 0):

1)I would suggest you to create an `HttpModule` that "catch" all  the search terms used by the users. How and where you will dump those information(you said you will use a SQL box) it's another matter which is outside the scope of the module which should just catch the Search tems.
Then you can create a component that contains the login to store those information using Async call(or even a third part component like Log4Net )

2) if you want create a kind of batch insert caching all the information you need to store and  at some point dump them on SQL I would use `MSMQ` or any other technology that support the `Reliability`: I think you want loose all those information in the case of a system-crash,etc